# How can I make an expandable notification in HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, popupwindow

What I am looking to do is have a notification numbers show in the top right corner of my site, that when a user clicks it, it opens up a notification menu or even a pop up box that says the notification. How can I code that? Thanks!

Comment: Sort of, my web host only allows for HTML and JavaScript. (or so it says)

Comment: Then I don't believe you can. You'd need a server side language to push the data.

Comment: Okay, do you know of an alternative method or a way to upload Java to the server? It's being ran through WebStarts. It seems to partly understand Java. It gets it right sometimes, but others it's way off.

Comment: It does allow you to upload Flash files, could I create a flash file that would complete this task?

Comment: could you please clarify the question by saying exactly how you recieve the notifications? Are they from the server?

Comment: They will need to be direct from the site itself, not the server. It needs to be part of the HTML code or JavaScript. Nothing fancy, just a colored banner with a customizable message that has a close button that gets rid of the banner.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, there are many:

http://medleyweb.com/web-dev/10-great-jquery-notification-plugins

For all the tastes!

Cheers.

Comment: He has no server side environment; just a free website builder called webstarts.

Answer (score -1):

Some ways you can do that:

1.) If the data or notification details are in the database, then you can just COUNT the ROWS that are untapped or not seen (you can do this by having a "status" column which identified if the row/notification had already been seen or not) by that specific user, its better that every notification must be saved in the database.
2.) Put the COUNTED ROWS you fetch from the database inside a div tag and declare an Id in it.
3.) When you already fetching the right data, then put the correct CSS/styles where you want to put the notification number including the property z-index:100;.
4.) Same goes with the pop up box, when the user click the div tag, first hide the div tag for notification numbers, then you must fetch all the data from the database putting in inside another div tag with CSS for notification details.
5.) This can be done greatly with javascript and jquery.

Jquery is also great in communicating to server, use it for real time purposes :)
Hope this helps :)

Comment: No database. He's using a free website builder called webstarts.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - He didn't even clarify where the notification came from, so i expected that it must be from the database.